# Can "Keep looking back" cover the act of looking back repeatedly at an interval of a few seconds?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I wonder if "Keep looking back" can describe the act of looking back repeatedly at an interval of a few seconds.

For example, you are walking along the sidewalk and a man is walking in the same direction as you are. And while he is walking, he looks back at you for a second and keeps looking forward and this happens again and again like at an interval of several seconds.

This is not him looking back continuously but it is repeated.

In this case, can we say "He keeps looking back (at us) while walking. He is suspicious."?

Comment: Yes, "keep" + VERB-ing can be used to indicate both repeated and continuous actions.

Comment: Something can *keep happening* several times a second, or repeatedly at intervals of centuries or more, so the "interval length" isn't relevant to *repeated* activities. But you could feasibly urge someone to *keep living* even though they've obviously been doing this *continuously* beforehand, not *repetitively*.

Comment: To emphasize that the action is repetitive, it is idiomatic in NAmE to use _keep on_ in place of _keep,_ thus: _"He keeps on looking back (at us) while walking."_

Comment: @FumbleFingers I appreciate your elegant explanation. But I can not understand it. Can you describe it in a easier way to understand? I am not a native English speaker so sometimes even a bit easy expressions for a native can be very hard to understand. I will appreciate your mercy! :)

Comment: For example, I could say [the plane of earth's orbit (obliquity) keeps oscillating between 22.1 and 24.5 degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt), even though it only makes one oscillation every 41,000 years (just because something *keeps* happening doesn't necessarily mean it's happening very fast). With that particular example it's a matter of emphasis / interpretation whether it's a continuous or a repeated action, but I could also say *Life on earth keeps being knocked back by mass extinctions* (an 'action' that 'repeats' irregularly every few hundred million years)

Comment: ...The basic point, as TRomano says, is that *to keep [verb]ing* can either mean *to [verb] continously* (as in *Don't stop now! Keep walking!*), or it can mean *to [verb] again and again, repeatedly* (as in *Don't keep asking me about that!*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now I understand you, FumbleFingers! Thank you very much. Your explanation was a very sophisticated, and also somewhat philosophical. I am impressed by your idea regarding the matter!

Comment: In this particular case I think it might be a good idea for *you yourself* to post an answer to your own question here (copy or adapt anything from my comments that seems useful). Note that with the specific verb you're asking about we could imagine, for example, *Turn your head and keep looking back for a minute while I prepare my 'magic trick'* (continuous action), as opposed to *I wish you wouldn't keep looking back at that guy behind us every time he coughs* (repeated action).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I greatly appreciate your comments. The examples are elegant and so helpful to me. But, I would try to post an answer as you said, another person posted an answer now so I don't know whether to do so. What do you think I should do?

Comment: What I think is that *in your specific example*, it simply wouldn't occur to native speakers to interpret *keeps looking back* as describing a "continuous" action. So whilst @Jay's answer is perfectly correct in that ***glancing*** inherently forces the "repetitive" interpretation, it's really "writing advice" dealing with a "non-problem". In my "obliquity" example, I think few people would even realise that either (or both?) interpretations might apply - perhaps because in practice there's little or no meaningful "real-world" difference.

Comment: ...That's why I suggested it might be good for you to write your own answer. As a non-native speaker you probably have a clearer sense of the potential ambiguity so concisely summarised by TRomano's first comment. We native speakers tend not to even be aware of potential ambiguities like this (if it created *real* problems even for us, very likely the way we use ***keep [verbing]*** would have changed by now anyway).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am sure that now I have got your point pretty well. Thank you for keeping giving me elegant and kind advice and explanations very much. I will write my own answer after settling how to write even though I already understand the point you taught me. :)

Comment: I'm glad we seem to have achieved a meeting of minds here. Bear in mind my point here is just a personal opinion (not necessarily held by others). But it does often seem to me that nns are actually ***better*** than native speakers at answering certain questions, because they're more likely to understand why *other* nns might have problems with a usage. I find it particularly interesting when it turns out that an nns of a *particular* language can explain something to another speaker of that language where we Anglophones barely even understand why *anyone* might find it "problematic".

Answer (score 1):

"He keeps glancing back (at us) while he is walking."

There is some room for confusing about who is said to be walking.

Using "glancing" prevents creating an image of someone continuously looking back while walking forward.

Comment: Wow, this is also a good answer.